# read.table only reads the first 835873 rows

Tags: r, csv, import, dataset, bigdata

So I have this tsv dataset made of 19,150,868 rows; I know for sure the number is correct because A) it was specified by the owner of the file and B) I checked using `wc -l` in UNIX.

Yet, when I ran:

```
MyData = read.table("dataset.tsv", header=FALSE, sep="\t",
col.names = c_names, colClass = "character", comment.char = "",
quote="", nrows = 19150868)
```

Only the first 835873 got imported. No error is thrown, and the process only takes 20.33 seconds.

Comment: Is there anything strange about that particular row? Do the read-in lines in R look as they should?

Comment: @Thomas: The last line fetched is `835873 user_000033 2007-05-24T19:50:25Z ~8+ Å¤Ä`.

Comment: I'm assuming that is not what it's supposed to look like? If that's the case, play around with the `fileEncoding` parameter in `read.table`.

Comment: @Thomas: I tried different encodings but none of them works... :(

Comment: You probably have an embedded Ctrl-Z which is causing R to abort the read prematurely. The easiest thing to do may be to edit the file to remove it.

Comment: Try creating a file with just the last line successfully read and then the next few lines after that, and try to read that.

Comment: Did you check the encoding of the file?