# How to open this tsv with R?

Tags: r, import, csv

I'd like to open this tsv file : userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv (http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~ocelma/MusicRecommendationDataset/lastfm-1K.html)

I know this file contains 19,150,868 rows but when I read this file with R I only obtain 835K rows.

```
setwd('C:/xxx/lastfm-dataset-1K.tar/lastfm-dataset-1K')

df <- read.table('userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv', header=F, sep='\t', fill=T, quote='')
```

Sometimes some columns are empty, this is why I'm using `fill=T`.

I'm pretty sure the problem comes from special characters.
The last line fetched is: `user_000033 2007-05-24T19:50:25Z ~8+ Å¤Ä`

I tried several `fileEncoding` but none of them works.

**EDIT:**

Someone else had the same issue with the exact same file, but no answer have been identified :
[read.table only reads the first 835873 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482933/read-table-only-reads-the-first-835873-rows?rq=1)

I finally did it with Python and it works :

```
import pandas as pd     
import csv
df = pd.read _csv('userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, header=None , sep='\t', na_values=[''],  error_bad_lines=False)
```

So the question is : **How to do the same with R ?** Why the weird characters cause a problem to R and not to Python ?

Comment: I think the best thing might be to store the data in a SOLite database. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/sqldf-for-Very-Large-Tab-Delimited-Files-td4350555.html

Comment: I would recommend `fread` from the `data.table` package for that size of data

Comment: @mkemp6 `fread`doesn't work because it can't handle rows with missing columns :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597488/fill-option-for-fread

Comment: @Stephane do you have an opportunity to preprocess with awk or python?

Comment: @mkemp6. Yes, I did it in Python and it works *(see update)*.
 I don't really understand why the weird characters cause a problem to R and not to Python ! :/

Comment: @Stephane, why not add the extra commas in Python then write out so you can read into R with `fread`?

Comment: @mkemp6. This is what I did, but I'd like to understand what's wrong. I'm curious :)

Answer (score 3):

I think SQLite is a good idea, and here is how I was able to implement it

From a shell:

```
$ sqlite3 test.db
```

Then in sqlite:

```
sqlite> create table test (userid text, timestamp text, artid text, artname text, traid text, traname text);
sqlite> .separator "\t"
sqlite> .import userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv test
```

Then back in R:

```
R> library(RSQLite)
Loading required package: DBI
R> conn <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname='test.db')
R> df <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM test")
R> nrow(df)
[1] 15121996
```

Its not 19 million, but its close enough on a difficult dataset

Comment: Why we don't have all the rows with this solution ?

Comment: Because there are likely tabs in the song names, which R or SQLite interpret as the start of a new column. You could always use vi or emacs to edit the file and manually add your own field separator.